# Sticky overlay images while scrolling

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll

Anyone knows how is this achieved using jQuery, HTML and CSS? I attached a picture of the part I am curious. Basically while scrolling, on the left side the text is scrolling while on the right side the images are on top of each other and revealed?

Any help is much appreciated

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

[image]

Comment: **Please clarify the question;** I don't see any **images**, so which **images** are you talking about?

Comment: Which **editor** is here in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many Jquery plugins available which can be used to reveal images on scroll.

One such is - https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/

Library used in the reference website - https://scrollmagic.io/examples/index.html